# Providing the maclaurin series for $\int_0^x te^{(-t)^2} dt$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin series for $\int_0^x te^{-t^2} dt$ ?

I know it has something to do with the Maclaurin series for $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$, but that's about it

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^xte^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$? $\int_0^xte^{(-t)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^xte^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: Use the fact that $f'(x)=xe^{x^2} $ and then keep differentiating to get $f (x)=f (0)+xf'(0)+\frac {x^2}{2!}f''(0)+.. $

Comment: @robjohn oops, my bad, yes that's what I meant sorry!

Comment: Use $f^\prime(x)=xe^{-x^2}$, find the series for $e^{-x^2}$ from the series for $e^{-x}$ and multiply the result by $x$. Finally, integrate the result to get the series for $f(x)$.

Comment: I take that back, it's better to just evaluate the integral first and use the series for $e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

$$f(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^xt\,e^{-t^2}\,dt=\left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t^2}\right]_0^x
=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)$$

We know that Maclaurin's series for $e^{-x}$ is

\begin{equation}
e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\,\dfrac{x^k}{k!}
\end{equation}

therefore the series for $e^{-x^2}$ is

\begin{equation}
e^{-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\,\dfrac{x^{2k}}{k!}
\end{equation}

Therefore

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\,\dfrac{x^{2k}}{k!}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\,\dfrac{x^{2k}}{2k!}
\end{eqnarray}